# class searchByQos" neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web .xml

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, juddi

i 'm trying to run sample SearchByQos :https://github.com/apache/juddi/blob/master/juddi-client-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/v3/client/cli/SearchByQos.java
it displays error :
class searchByQos" neither has a main method nor is it a servlet specified in web .xml

so i add @WebServlet(name = "SearchByQos", urlPatterns = {"/SearchByQos"})
public class SearchByQos extends HttpServlet {
but it displays other errors:

```
    Infos:   visiting unvisited references

Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer prepare method
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app
Grave:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
    ... 40 more
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
    ... 40 more

Grave:   Exception while preparing the app : Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Infos:   visiting unvisited references
Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer prepare method
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
    ... 40 more

Grave:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeEndpointAddress(WebServiceEndpoint.java:691)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.composeFinalWsdlUrl(WebServiceEndpoint.java:754)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.doWebServicesDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:625)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:177)
    ... 40 more
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app : Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet UDDIClientSubscriptionListenerImpl implements 2 web service endpoints  but must only implement 1
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.updateServletEndpointRuntime(WebServiceEndpoint.java:1004)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebServiceEndpoint.getEndpointAddressPath(WebServiceEndpoint.java:718)


    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

thank you

Comment: could you help me it stay errors , thank you

Answer (score 0):

The search by qos can be exercised using the example in the juddi source code (and the distribution).

Start the jUDDI Tomcat server

Under https://github.com/apache/juddi/tree/master/juddi-examples/more-uddi-samples

Run `mvn clean install -Pinteractive`

When prompted, login, then run the sample 6

> 6) Find Service by QOS Parameters (Binding/tModelInstanceInfo)

You should see output similiar to the following

`killing mary's business if it exists
making mary's tmodel key gen
saving...
fetching business list
before no service returned!
saving mary
1 service returned after
hey it worked as advertised. Here's all the services with QOS parameters
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<serviceList truncated="false" xmlns="urn:uddi-org:api_v3">
    <listDescription>
        <includeCount>1</includeCount>
        <actualCount>1</actualCount>
        <listHead>1</listHead>
    </listDescription>
    <serviceInfos>
        <serviceInfo serviceKey="uddi:uddi.marypublisher.com:marybusinessoneservice" businessKey="uddi:uddi.marypublisher.com:marybusinessone">
            <name xml:lang="en">name!</name>
        </serviceInfo>
    </serviceInfos>
</serviceList>`

### Explanation of what's happening:

1. If the test mary business exists, it's first deleted (it's used in other samples)
2. It queries all businesses that contains a QoS tModel, none are returned
3. It creates a new business + service + binding belonging to Mary with QoS parameters
4. It then queries all businesses than contains a QoS tModel and the new service is returned.

### Now on to why this part is important.

The module `juddi-client-cli` is nearly identical to the `more-uddi-samples` in form and function. Start it using the same mechanism. The only difference is that the cli tool won't delete or add stuff unless you tell it do (a query, will not modify anything on the server). It's meant to be an administrative tool to run in cases that juddi-gui cannot be used.

### Querying for a business that has a QoS parameter for itself or any child object

Not sure what your goal is but i suspect this is what you need.

`FindBusiness fb = new FindBusiness();
fb.setAuthInfo(token);
//find all businesses
org.uddi.api_v3.FindQualifiers fq = new org.uddi.api_v3.FindQualifiers();
fq.getFindQualifier().add(UDDIConstants.APPROXIMATE_MATCH);
fq.getFindQualifier().add(UDDIConstants.OR_ALL_KEYS);
fb.setFindQualifiers(fq);
// with any name
fb.getName().add((new Name(UDDIConstants.WILDCARD, null)));
fb.setTModelBag(new TModelBag());
//where something references one of the WSDM WoS Constants
fb.getTModelBag().getTModelKey().addAll(WSDMQosConstants.getAllQOSKeys());
BusinessList list= inquiry.findBusiness(fb);`

Comment: it displays error build faild when i run mvn clean install -Pinteractive

Comment: what's the error? did you change the server port? if so update the uddi.xml file

Comment: error build: BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project juddi-client: Compilation failure

Comment: are you running from within an ide? run it outside the ide from a command prompt/terminal

Comment: yes, i run mvn clean install -Pinteractive from  prompt/terminal

Comment: please post the output

Comment: please, how and where ? i couldn't do that in add comment and in answser your question

Comment: git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi.git then cd juddi, then mvn clean install -DskipTests=true, start tomcat on port 8080 from juddi-tomcat/target/tomcat/.... then cd juddi-client-cli, then mvn install -Pinteractive

Comment: hi spy it was ok fo git clone... but for command mvn clean install... it display error , i try it sever time :( need help please

Comment: Post the output or link to paste bin