# Login failed in juddi

Tags: web-services, uddi

I was trying to login juddi version **3.3.4**. I had configured tomcat user and the connection was ok in other pc but on this pc it gave an error :

> Login failed: error Error Could not send
>   Message.javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException

could you help me?

thank you for your help

Comment: can you be more specific? Login failed when calling the web service, or via the juddi web user interface?

Comment: via  the juddi web user interface ,when i introduce login :uddi and password:uddi

Comment: check to see if http://localhost:8080/juddiv3 is deployed. i saw a similar issue recently. Also what jdk? is this the repackaged tomcat server right?

Comment: localhost:8080/juddiv3 is deployed corenctly but it stay error when i login.  jdk1.8.0_144,jre1.8.0_144,for tomcat 'juddi-tomcat-3.3.4' folder is in folder juddi-distro-3.3.4.  i test this in an other computer with the same configuration it was ok

Comment: did you change the port by chance?

Comment: also check the server logs, there should be more information to go on there

Comment: yes i change port to 8081 thats all. server log ok i 'll check it and i'll replay

Comment: where can i  copy the log in the forum?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the port that tomcat runs on, juddi-gui also needs to be update. It has a configuration file located in `juddi-gui/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/uddi.xml`
Edit that file and update the ports for the `default` node. That should restore functionality.

This is of course assuming that you've downloaded the juddi distribution and are running the sample tomcat server instance.

Comment: it's ok , i have change port in uddi.xml ;) thank you so much :)

Comment: could you help me for this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653944/class-searchbyqos-neither-has-a-main-method-nor-is-it-a-servlet-specified-in-we    ?i 'm tying to execute the example to be able to search it in juddi . thank you